# Azure DevOps REST API List Items is not returning all items when using Full recursion

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-repos

I'm trying to use List Items to pull all files in a repository, as described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/items/list?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0&tabs=HTTP

I'm loading the following URL in a web browser:

```
https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repo id}/items?scopePath=/&recursionLevel=Full&api-version=7.0
```

but it's only returning a single item for the root path:

```
{
    "count":1
    ,"value":
    [
        {
            "objectId":"64ad7e9229fc73509cadae9e545ed620a5d00846"
            ,"gitObjectType":"tree"
            ,"commitId":"8323c75114f5d06a156819358744a4fa3b9788d1"
            ,"path":"/"
            ,"isFolder":true
            ,"url":"https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repo}/items?path=%2F&versionType=Branch&versionOptions=None"
        }
    ]
}
```

- There are files in the repos.
- I've tested with a few repos in different projects -- same result.
- I've tried pulling from a subfolder, thinking that I'm hitting a data cap... no change, just the root of the selected folder.
- Other REST API works: I CAN get all Repos, get all Checkins, and get Changes from a given Checkin.
- I'm a system admin.

Why is only the root folder being returned? Any ideas?

EDIT:

Additional findings:

- It appears that the parameters are NOT case sensitive.
- Invalid, or made up, parameters are ignored (e.g., adding `&breakme=true` does not result in an error message.
- I added `IncludeMetadata` to test that case sensitivity is not an issue.

The following URL loads with the following result:

```
https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repo id}/items?recursionLevel=full&IncludeContentMetadata=true&breakme=true&api-version=7.0
```

Results

```
{
    "count": 1,
    "value":
    [
        {
            "objectId": "4fc34171cbcaf49141b45c3b9096c101a879c181",
            "gitObjectType": "tree",
            "commitId": "d43240daf04466e8fbbbb414e5ddd3dcf8a042d1",
            "path": "/",
            "isFolder": true,
            "contentMetadata":
            {
                "fileName": ""
            },
            "url": "https://dev.azure.com/{org}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repo}/items?path=%2F&versionType=Branch&versionOptions=None"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Please share the code where you're invoking this API. Also, although it *shouldn't* be case sensitive, the documentation states that the parameter value for `recursionLevel` is `full`, not `Full`.

Comment: I'm just pasting the URL into a web browser. I just checked... `Full` vs `full` has no change.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, this occures only on web browser such as Edge, but it does not occur on Logic Apps or Power Automate.

Comment: Thanks for this. I spent ages trying lots of combinations to get more than one result in Edge.  I was about to give up, then I read this answer, called it via C# code and it just worked. 

Comment: Strange, but true. I only get 1 result in Chrome and Edge, but all the results when using `curl` from a command line.

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to resolve the original problem, but the Trees dataset gave me a solid work around.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/trees/get?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0&tabs=HTTP